# inheritance from class,defined in th different namespace

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers, namespaces

I have 2 classes ,defined in the different namespaces :

```
//--==file1.hpp==--
namespace n1{
class x1 {
//.....
};
};
//--==file2.hpp==--
namespace n2{
class x1: public n1::x1{
//.....
    };
};

//--== file3.hpp ==--
namespace n2 {
 class x2 {
    private:
      n1::x1* data1_;
    public:
      void func(x1* data2) { data1_ = data2; }
  };
};
```

The compilation of this fails with

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from `'n2::x1 *' to 'n1::x1 *'`
```

I can`t understand what could be a problem,Since n2:x1 inherits from n1::x1...?
Thank you

Comment: Can you check whether (as your question suggests) the namespace is part of the problem by putting both classes in the same namespace to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: `//--== file3.hpp ==-- namespace2`?? `namespce n2` you mean?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN - it is very difficult to do it - many additional classes are based on it

Comment: Ok, but then it just works without any problems: http://ideone.com/DYQV8. Do you use forward type declarations?

Comment: Are you sure file3.hpp successfully #includes file2.hpp and file1.hpp? You'd get that error if `n2::x1` is only forward-declared.

Comment: Your code compiles fine on Visual C++ 2008, what compiler are you using? What line is causing the error?

Comment: Even if you can't test switching the namespace in the full application, you could write simple test code like you did above, just to test whether the namespace causes a problem in a simple case, and is affected by putting classes into the same namespace. It makes sense to at least see if you are trying to solve the right problem first.

Comment: the function void func(x1* data2) { data1_ = data2; } should be void func(n1::x1* data2) { data1_ = data2; } because x2 is in n2 which also has an x1 class. When you don't specify a specific namespace, the compiler looks in the current namespace first and if it finds a match it rolls with it.

Answer (score 3):

Inheritance from one namespace to another namespace class, should not have any compilation error. It is just that, in the sub-class, if you have to call the method of the parent class (which is in another namespace), you should use the complete name (with [namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)).

**For you reference:**

```
namespace a
{
class A1 {
 public:
    void testA1() {...}
};
}

namespace b
{
class B1: public class a::A1
{
 public:
    void testB1()
        {
          a::A1::testA1();
          ...
        }
};
}
```

But looks like, the above problem was just been a typo issue, and has been resolved. However, to clarify on the usage, sample code shall help.

Answer (score -1):

In file2.h: Include file1.h

In file3.h: Include file1.h and file2.h.

And in main include file3.h.

int main()
{

```
n2::x2 xx22;
n2::x1* xx11;
xx22.func(xx11);
```

}

This complies just fine.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem. If he haven't did the includes the compiler will generate a punch of errors not including the one he listed.

Comment: I did not say that he has not include anything. However this include order worked for me. Please try it with the above code.